# Bulk Insert not working with documentdb

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to insert multiple entries in documentdb through looping  for that
I have written a stored procedure in javascript, but sometimes times it some times not.

I think issue with documentdb and I am new with documentdb.

Can anyone help me out, how do I fix this issue??

Comment: try async module. for one by one insertion

Comment: Code please. Also, please let us know if your client-side is .NET, node.js, or what.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the entries to be inserted as a transaction where they either all succeed or they all fail, then you want to use a stored procedure. However, if that's not critical, you can do it client-side with multiple calls to `createDocument()` or `upsertDocument()`. That will give you better performance assuming you can parallelize the operation on the client side enough because it will fan the work out across secondaries. To get the correct parallelization on the client-side when using node.js, I recommend the use of [async.js](https://caolan.github.io/async/) in particular, [eachOfLimit()](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachOfLimit). You'll have to experimen to find the right parallelization limit, but start with 10 and go up from there until you either get the performance you want or you hit some client-side resource limit.